# How to fill an object with data in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

How is it possible to add data to a TestCaseSource object which contains a Dictionary?

I have following code:

```
static object[] FileInfoCases =
{
  new object[] {
    new Dictionary<string, List<BackupFileInfo>>() {
      ["source"] = new List<BackupFileInfo>() { },
      ["destination"] = new List<BackupFileInfo>() { }
    }
  }
};
```

BackupFileInfo is my Cutsom object. The values `FileName` and `FileLastChanged` and `FullPath` are Attributes of my custom object. Now I want to fill the List. My custom object is not static. I can not access the attribute names within the list.

Can someone help me please?

EDIT: have updated my code-snippet

Answer (score 1):

If you need to go beyond setting properties in this way, keep in mind that the source can be a method. That allows you to do any initialization you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have found myself the answer ;)

```
static object[] FileInfoCases = {
  new object[] {
    new Dictionary<string, List<BackupFileInfo>>() {
      ["source"] = new List<BackupFileInfo>() {
        new BackupFileInfo() {
          FileName = "",
          FileLastChanged = new DateTime(),
          FullPath =""
        }
      },
      ["destination"] = new List<BackupFileInfo>() { }
    }
  }
};
```